# WSO2 DataPublisher

Tags: wso2, cluster-computing, thrift, complex-event-processing, wso2-cep

We have a 2 node WSO2 CEP cluster.

We wanted to send events via thrift to the CEP cluster. 
We are using Wso2 databridge - DataPublisher on the client side. While we are able to send events over thrift to one CEP, but not sure how can we send events to the cluster.

We tried using the comma seperated thrift URL but the DataPublisher fails with MalformedURLException ?

Any suggestions ?

Thanks
Rajiv Patil

Answer (score 0):

You have used the pure **DataPublisher**. In order to use comma separated URL's you need to used **LoadBalancingDataPublisher** which is a wrapped version of **DataPublisher** enabling load balancing.

Comment: How can we make the WSO2 CEP use the LoadBalancingDataPublisher to connect to a BAM cluster ?

Comment: I have not worked with that class but as I see, you should add ReceiverGroup for CEP cluster, having DataPublisherHolder for each CEP server. You can check the implementation in org/wso2/carbon/databridge/agent/thrift/lb/LoadBalancingDataPublisher.java